# python manage.py runserver shows an old webapp page I developed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-react

I am learning Django so I've created many Django webapps under one directory. For example,

```
\webapps
  \polls
    \polls
    \api
    \manage.py
    ...
  \ponynote
    \ponynote
    \frontend
    \manage.py
    ...
```

I didn't use a *virtualenv* for developing django apps. I don't know whether it's the reason that causes the problem as below.

**App 1**
`python manage.py runserver` works all fine. (default port 8000)

**App 2**
`python manage.py runserver` still shows the **App 1 page.**

Method I tried:

- change the *port* `python manage.py runserver 8001`, it shows **App 2 page**.
- try to find the process ID PID, and kill it. No sign of port 8000.

However, this isn't the best solution since I can't change the port everytime when developing a new django app. Does anyone have a clue why this happens? Kudos.

**Problem solved:**
remove **web browser cache**. In my case, it's Chrome.

Comment: DId you try to restart your PC?

Comment: If you are using chrome, can you try incognito?

Comment: If you run both of them at the same time, you may run into problems. Try running both of them in different ports.

Comment: I agree, more likely it's cache

Comment: @bdbd  It's the cache. I tried to run in incognito. It worked. Kudos. Then I deleted cache to run in Chrome. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

One effective solution would be to create a bash script for your use. Create 2 separate bash scripts for your projects (The same dir where your project's manage.py can be found).

For App 1:

```
# script- App 1
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

For App 2:

```
# script- App 2
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

And for running:

```
./yourbashscriptfile
```